# Why is the word "what" used instead of "where"?

Tags: relative-pronouns, free-relative-clauses

I came across this sentence

> During the summer, the tribes who lived in **what** is now Florida often
>   slept in wooden frames with roofs but no walls.

This is from history textbook in the U.S. I think this "what" is a relative pronoun.Can I use "what" when I indicate the place? Is "where" appropriate in this sentence?

Answer (score 4):

> *During the summer, the tribes who lived in **what is now Florida** often
>   slept in wooden frames with roofs but no walls*.

No, 'where' would not be appropriate here. This is called a 'fused' relative construction where the antecedent and the relativised element are fused together instead of being expressed separately as in simpler relative constructions. Thus, the expression ‘what is now Florida’ is an NP whose head is fused with the first element in the relative clause. This means that 'what’ is both head of the NP and subject of the relative clause giving a meaning like that of the non-fused ‘the tribes who lived in ***the place which*** is now Florida'.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Can I use the word "what" in stead of "the place which"?

Comment: Yes, that's fine and normal.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. And can I reword like "the tribes who lived where the place is now Florida"?

Comment: No, 'where' is not possible there, but you could say 'the tribes who lived where Florida is now', which has the same meaning.

Comment: What is difference between "where the place is now Florida" and "where Florida is now'?

Comment: "Where" means 'the place which', so 'where the place is now Florida' means 'the place which the place is now Florida', which makes no sense and is ungrammatical.

Comment: How about "where now is Florida"?

Comment: You could have written "where now is Florida" 200 years ago, in very formal English, but it's not modern English. Actually, "where Florida is *now*" is a bit strange, because "Florida" has *always* been in that place. "Where Disney World is now" would be OK, because Disney World didn't exist in Orlando, Florida before 1971.

Comment: “where X is now” is common, but I wouldn't expect it for an extensive region with mostly natural boundaries (Florida *the peninsula* was already there before humans came).

Comment: Many thanks for the comments. They are very helpful for my English studying.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sentence

> What is the 27th state of the United States?

The answer is Florida. Yes, Florida is a place. But Florida is much more than a place. A State in the USA is a semiautonomous *political unit*. It has the power to form a government, tax its residents, formulate educational policies for its residents, say that it's compulsory for its residents to wear seat belts, draw up laws about self defense, and so forth.

In **what is now Florida**, 'Florida' is being thought of or conceptualized primarily as a *State*. Thus, native speakers use *what* here, and native speakers do not use *where* in a phrase such as '*where is now Florida'.